# WinDbg: print to another window

Tags: windbg

My WinDbg command window gets always polluted by useless AFW-traces... Therefore I would like to print my own stuff in another window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way that I'm aware of. You can use .ofilter to filter the output though, which may be sufficient.